# Is it possible to put an if statement within an If statements like so?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to put an if statement within an if statement. 
It seems to work until the last echo command in the script which doesn't print.

For testing I have created a directory with the same name as the $foldername which is input via a prompt. I am inputting this during the execution of the script. During the running of the script I am choosing the option to overwrite the directory, which works fine. However, I am confused as to why after the folder has been replaced, the script doesn't then move onto the last echo statement:

```
echo "Folder $foldername has now been created"
```

This is not being printed on screen which suggest the script isn't exiting the if statement section. Any ideas why?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please input the folder name you would like to create then press ENTER"
read foldername

if [ -d "/home/location/test_directories/$foldername" ]
then
    echo "$foldername already exists"
    sleep 2
    echo
    echo
    echo "Do you want to overwrite this folder and start afresh?"
    read -p "Type Y overwrite the folder, or N to exit the script" -n 1 -r
    echo

    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
        echo "You have chosen to overwrite the folder $foldername"

        rm -rf /home/location/test_directories/$foldername; mkdir /home/location/test_directories/$foldername
        sleep 2
    else
        exit
    fi

    exit
else
    mkdir /home/location/test_directories/$foldername
fi

sleep 2
echo "Folder $foldername has now been created"
```

Comment: Erugh. The convention when writing programs is to indent your blocks of code rather than running it all down the left-hand side. FTFY.

Comment: consider your use of `exit`

Comment: @glennjackman far easier to see when the code's indented

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you may nest `if`-statements to your heart's content.

The issue with your code is, as pointed out in comments to the question, the two `exit` statements.  Taking a branch that triggers any of these will terminate the script.

As far as I can see, both `exit` statements are superfluous and may be removed.

You should also make a habit of double-quoting any variable handed to you by the user, for example `$foldername`. In this case, to be able to handle folder names with spaces.

... or with newlines, tabs or other "field separators" if you've modified `IFS`, or with `*`, `?`, `[` that are special to the shell, and more if you've enabled the `extglob` option in `bash`.